# Does amazon personalize SIMS and personalized ranking recipes support metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

I couldn't find anything mentioned in amazon personalize SIMS and personalized ranking documentation regarding these recipes supporting user/item metadata. Does SIMS and personalized ranking support metadata?

Answer (score 0):

"The Item-to-item similarities (SIMS) recipe is based on the concept of collaborative filtering. A SIMS model leverages user-item interaction data to recommend items similar to a given item. In the absence of sufficient user behavior data for an item, this recipe recommends popular items." [1]

**Therefore, SIMS does not use metadata.**

Personalized Ranking uses the Feature Transformer with ARN  `arn:aws:personalize:::feature-transformation/JSON-percentile-filtering`
This is the same as the ARN used by *HRNN*, which explicitly only uses interactions (there is an *HRNN-Metadata* recipe for that). [2][3][4]

**Therefore, Personalized Ranking does not use metadata.**

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/native-recipe-sims.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/native-recipe-search.html

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/native-recipe-hrnn.html

[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/native-recipe-hrnn-metadata.html

Comment: Thank you.. your answers did help!

Comment: The info on Personalized-Ranking is no longer accurate. This recipe now trains on interactions (required) as well as item and user metadata if provided. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/personalized-ranking-recipes.html#personalized-ranking-overview